# SIMD Intrinsics difference between Vector<T>, advsimd and sse?

Tags: c#, .net, simd, intrinsics

If you look in the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Numerics/Matrix4x4.cs) of the [`System.Numerics.Matrix4x4`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.matrix4x4) class of .NET under multiply and other functions, it does an `if` check to see if hardware supports respectively:

```
if (AdvSimd.Arm64.IsSupported) {} else if (Sse.IsSupported) {}
```

But the generic [`System.Numerics.Vector<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector-1) struct seems to do all the same, what is the difference? Does `Vector<T>` not simply look behind the scenes and use whichever is available, and then a software fallback if none of them are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# `System.Numerics` `Vector<T>` generic SIMD doesn't expose all the shuffles and other ISA-specific things like x86 `movmskps`.  If you can get the job done efficiently with the common subset of functionality exposed with the generic API, I'd assume that would be a good choice and still compile to the instructions you'd exepct.

But the function you mentioned uses `Sse.Shuffle` (`shufps`) or `AdvSimd.Arm64.FusedMultiplyAddBySelectedScalar` (?) to broadcast and mul+add.  If ARM64 can actually do that in a single instruction (scalar broadcast source for a vector multiply), that's pretty cool.  The predecessor to AVX-512 could do that, KNC new instructions in early Xeon Phi, but even AVX-512 needs a shuffle and a separate FMA.  (Unless the operand is coming from memory: AVX-512 can use a broadcast memory source operand.)

I don't see any shuffles at all in the docs you linked for `System.Numerics`, only pure vertical SIMD, so that's not very useful for a 4x4 matrix product where each `row[i]` needs to get multiplied by a `broadcast(col[i])` vector.

So `System.Numerics` looks way more crippled that [GNU C native vectors](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html) in C and C++ where there at least is a `__builtin_shuffle`, but still missing out on special shuffles, and stuff like x86 `movmskps` to get a scalar bitmap of SIMD compare results.  (Which AMD and ARM64 have no direct equivalent for.)

Comment: Maybe it could have been done with the crippled `System.Numerics.Vector` API by using the broadcasting constructor, but then there's still the issue that you don't get to choose the vector size so you may get 256-bit vectors when you don't want them

Comment: @harold: I wondered about that, but guessed that might compile to a broadcast-load from memory instead of a shuffle.  (That might be a good thing on x86-64, especially with AVX-512).  It would certainly depend more on the compiler to do a good job extracting a scalar element and broadcasting it, so it makes sense that library code would be written to do it manually.  And yeah, always using the system's widest supported vector is not what you want for a small fixed-size use-case, only for "traditional" SIMD problems over large arrays.

Comment: That broadcast constructor tends (in this sort of case) to compile to something like `vmovss xmm0, [somewhere] \ vbroadcastss ymm0, xmm0`. It hurts to look at.